# How Can I Upload the any file from Android to PHP Server

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, file-upload, server

How Can I Upload the any file from  file explorer in Android to PHP Server like .pdf , .doc , .jpg etc.. i am able send only .jpg file using this example

https://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/selecting-image-from-gallery-or-taking-image-from-camera-with-options-menu-uploading-to-server/

Comment: using `multipartentity()` for  any file attachment can help. Or use `Retrofit2` which will help you to connect with your server along with file uploads. Learn about implementation of  `Retrofit2` here [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1132/retrofit2#t=201708020627258919618)

Comment: can we do it with volley do you have any link  for retrofit?

Comment: Volley is used only for server communication/networking in android. Read its documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2800/volley#t=201708020647073341706) and for retrofit2 you can use the link from my previous comment.

Comment: I use library `Fast Android Networking`. I hate retrofit